# Updating status timespan and removing unneeded rows with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, delete-row, timespan

Let's say I have some servers, and they are constantly updating a database with their status.

I need to run some reports on the status of these servers.  Doing a little cleanup on the tables would really help out.

I get 2 timestamps for each status message (start time and end time).  What I'd like to do is take ensuing updates that have the same status, and remove them.  I want to update the end time to reflect the proper interval.

Let me illustrate...

server_status table:

```
server   |    status    |     start_time      |       end_time
---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------
 web1    |  running     | 2013-06-04 00:00:00 | 2013-06-04 00:05:00
 web2    |  down        | 2013-06-04 00:01:00 | 2013-06-04 00:03:00
 web1    |  running     | 2013-06-04 00:05:00 | 2013-06-04 01:00:00
 msdb    |  idle        | 2013-06-04 00:02:00 | 2013-06-04 02:00:00
 web1    |  running     | 2013-06-04 01:00:00 | 2013-06-04 02:00:00
 web2    |  down        | 2013-06-04 00:03:00 | 2013-06-04 03:00:00
 web2    |  running     | 2013-06-04 03:00:00 | 2013-06-04 05:00:00
 web1    |  maintenance | 2013-06-04 02:00:00 | 2013-06-04 05:00:00
 web1    |  running     | 2013-06-04 05:00:00 | 2013-06-04 07:00:00
```

i'd like my table to end up looking like this (sorted on start_time):

```
server   |    status    |     start_time      |       end_time
---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------
 web1    |  running     | 2013-06-04 00:00:00 | 2013-06-04 02:00:00
 web2    |  down        | 2013-06-04 00:01:00 | 2013-06-04 03:00:00
 msdb    |  idle        | 2013-06-04 00:02:00 | 2013-06-04 02:00:00
 web1    |  maintenance | 2013-06-04 02:00:00 | 2013-06-04 05:00:00
 web2    |  running     | 2013-06-04 03:00:00 | 2013-06-04 05:00:00
 web1    |  running     | 2013-06-04 05:00:00 | 2013-06-05 07:00:00
```

This let's me know exactly when my boxes changed states,  and then when I run some reports on these tables, I can query BETWEEN the start_time and end_time in SQL.

Any clue how to do this?  I'm assuming I'll need an update statement, and then a delete.  I can add row numbers if I need to, although they don't currently exist.  It may be necessary, so we can sort and then check to see if the server and status at row X is the same at row X + 1.

Running postgres 8.1 (I know, I know.  going to 8.4 soon).

Comment: Check the row of sample data I added to make sure it's correct both on input and on output. Sample data needs a discontinuous, later row that has the same status as an earlier row.

Comment: yeah.  it looks right.  i must've missed something.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky problem, because you have multiple groups of values for the same `(server, status)`, so a simple `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT (ON)` won't cut it.

However, the [window function **`lag()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) (available since PostgreSQL **8.4**) is a perfect fit for your problem, making the solution surprisingly simple.

To get the values you are looking for in a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT server, status, start_time, end_time
FROM  (
   SELECT *, status IS DISTINCT FROM 
             lag(status) OVER (PARTITION BY server ORDER BY start_time) AS step
   FROM   server_status
   ) sub
WHERE  step
ORDER  BY start_time;
```

Legacy version: this should work with **8.1**, too. Only tested with 8.4.
The correlated subquery is probably a lot slower than the window function.

```
SELECT server, status, start_time, end_time
FROM   server_status s
WHERE ( 
   SELECT s1.status
   FROM   server_status s1
   WHERE  s1.server = s.server
   AND    s1.start_time < s.start_time
   ORDER  BY s1.start_time DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) IS DISTINCT FROM s.status
ORDER  BY start_time;
```

[**->SQLfiddle for both**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!11/bc1d3/2)
To `DELETE` rows as required:

```
DELETE FROM server_status s
USING (
   SELECT server, status, start_time
         ,status IS DISTINCT FROM
          lag(status) OVER (PARTITION BY server ORDER BY start_time) AS step
   FROM   server_status
   ) d
WHERE  s.server = d.server
AND    s.status = d.status
AND    s.start_time = d.start_time
AND    NOT d.step;
```

For `8.1`. Only tested with 8.4.

```
DELETE FROM server_status s
WHERE (   
   SELECT s1.status = s.status
   FROM   server_status s1
   WHERE  s1.server = s.server
   AND    s1.start_time < s.start_time
   ORDER  BY s1.start_time DESC
   LIMIT  1
   );
```

Any **index** on `(server, start_time)` will greatly improve performance for bigger tables, for *any* of these queries.

You *need* to upgrade, for security reasons alone. (But why stop at 8.4? Go straight to the current version.

Comment: i always get a little flack for the 8.1 thing.  the issue is that i am still confined by red hat 5, and RH5 only supports up to 8.4.  upgrading postgres hasn't been a priority, so we've still been stuck on 8.1.  the move to RH6 will be a nightmare, so that's not happening any time soon.  sadly, i can't use this solution without a lot of work to make it fit to 8.1.

Comment: @jasonmclose: You did mention 8.4 just again, right? You can use it there.

Comment: yeah.  we will be moving to 8.4 in a few months, but i was hoping to sneak this in under our build that still uses 8.1

Comment: @jasonmclose: I gave in and added a legacy version.